# Plotting 2 variables with different values on one ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot these two variables on a single plot using geom_line. I am trying to plot this in ggplot but cannot seem to get the two y axis to line up, they are different values but I want them to have scales on each side to compare the trends in both lines of the data. Depth will go on the x-axis. I have tried the scale_y_continuous and sec.axis but the values do not match in scale either side. Any help is appreciated. The data i would like to plot is below.

```
1   0.173391562 28.59395158
2   0.214361872 33.7366968
3   0.308646363 46.2949179
4   0.257708524 37.89447248
5   0.224897551 34.32860265
6   0.145171163 28.08528395
7   0.173999818 24.80078261
8   0.270944328 32.50899326
9   0.261010924 29.01270011
10  0.361983723 36.3893962
11  0.359390622 36.15984121
12  0.333525205 31.44924086
13  0.33768052  33.00353711
14  0.309981922 31.42805635
15  0.330494717 36.28325127
16  0.181157502 20.88911761
17  0.254215293 27.26910498
18  0.293612873 34.93205204
19  0.24907632  30.5315156
20  0.346434266 40.64330918
21  0.378512527 40.61580559
22  0.302215651 35.26491587
23  0.355436135 41.01255292
24  0.502130416 52.41091739
25  0.410146235 46.33041878
26  0.30681494  33.08084756
27  0.329023045 35.56066693
28  0.541758489 54.02387432
29  0.526078282 50.2425805
30  0.561494219 51.33047207
31  0.493565182 49.66426074
32  0.417354048 46.20546128
33  0.417266448 44.30758835
34  0.403718982 43.44632528
35  0.376484957 41.09212147
36  0.450941795 52.43820402
37  0.431716168 47.89665099
38  0.44666017  49.12036227
39  0.269821452 31.1403291
40  0.340717454 37.96676039
41  0.31589745  33.83486191
42  0.31732477  32.46178394
43  0.35595406  42.04289719
44  0.37488539  42.94878615
45  0.476799527 52.50130094
46  0.414186557 46.9859969
47  0.34681511  41.76511178
48  0.25607998  39.07549843
49  0.374076147 44.33285268
50  0.306767197 32.36392051
51  0.378731062 42.46894432
52  0.403964799 46.72974472
53  0.400208086 46.86924313
54  0.378346003 45.93401959
55  0.32334982  40.653891
56  0.370413611 46.20852146
57  0.384627133 48.3534753
58  0.326566693 38.47417084
59  0.295066197 35.50923881
60  0.263170286 31.41705269
61  0.323361255 41.28035198
62  0.399347329 53.34552952
63  0.248387917 34.55188721
64  0.270008537 37.50595681
65  0.283705557 35.80119095
66  0.197849673 25.40296193
67  0.33659096  42.33051465
68  0.303983749 40.78436013
69  0.343069061 40.96636248
70  0.323109391 36.81320321
71  0.300774802 35.06545911
72  0.398124679 47.21331738
73  0.377987258 42.80787736
74  0.461865725 50.32148045
75  0.475877312 57.53193401
76  0.357318402 42.95249723
77  0.34805004  42.75479572
78  0.381084073 43.93093005
79  0.29760908  34.02775395
80  0.367957674 40.87432243
81  0.318750527 38.28122973
82  0.374989555 48.97633729
83  0.347177    42.98279363
84  0.355768141 47.10758559
85  0.322363129 43.30868005
86  0.432422048 60.33585503
87  0.366984102 50.46299328
88  0.412559129 55.82554367
89  0.433232316 57.59871719
90  0.301347244 39.21425595
91  0.270191476 35.09670669
92  0.344342693 45.61218865
93  0.372873381 51.98181828
94  0.389315422 50.98812087
95  0.254513501 31.68490516
96  0.285697617 39.5796553
97  0.348835394 43.7137552
98  0.25281053  31.55264459
99  0.261910454 34.26807363
100 0.259161133 35.46524475
101 0.332617316 45.12231676
102 0.325281364 41.61330722
103 0.294936998 37.32182524
104 0.313459251 38.3328084
105 0.26394759  30.93780017
106 0.24809482  33.04450699
107 0.195192647 26.74856346
108 0.233084193 32.9936559
109 0.238117341 34.17709205
110     
111 0.267439385 38.92927446
112 0.327251048 46.23487371
113 0.258863677 33.44979941
114 0.234736862 31.71360575
115 0.26061632  36.38692079
116 0.22098907  29.06811556
117 0.25723662  31.95658504
118 0.271517784 32.35599662
119 0.354704894 48.11113802
120 0.383684457 50.62708957
121 0.289619851 42.01865475
122 0.121607972 17.72229594
123 0.11509963  16.17907725
124 0.101273884 14.73828062
125 0.132470222 17.24243083
126 0.155197112 20.22051312
127 0.143407234 18.54988622
128 0.147550091 18.31398958
129 0.151921808 17.16723005
130 0.182333859 20.96238654
131 0.186135307 21.13495936
132 0.191695413 22.10796101
133 0.141766205 15.96856802
134 0.136846547 15.49472073
135 0.160658539 19.66978032
136 0.151965338 19.01196925
137 0.116093748 15.30017734
138 0.15835552  21.42748697
139 0.146782257 19.64407552
140 0.19939262  26.04119647
141 0.20749005  28.80692152
142 0.202486435 27.01627141
143 0.182114645 24.07220142
144 0.160004494 21.12325637
145 0.146253894 18.45749045
146 0.203739329 25.06268819
147 0.169513841 20.97263044
148 0.121736019 15.25017996
149 0.179502286 22.30932793
150 0.113560828 14.42010541
151 0.125100431 15.60498601
152 0.114431336 14.54320097
153 0.138231377 17.12560381
154 0.146741442 18.40903884
155 0.181144553 21.91730726
156 0.132336932 16.45398242
157 0.145189214 17.57853612
158 0.118433069 13.65532164
159 0.135446315 16.3140712
160 0.119681651 15.28765645
161 0.146792616 17.8533999
162 0.136816314 17.87085372
163 0.147536924 18.59142841
164 0.132012791 16.71069285
165 0.118887527 16.21477044
166 0.146804144 21.13860853
167 0.130986529 19.3671853
168 0.122128274 19.20187058
169 0.103402269 16.67974512
170 0.10263997  17.43100635
171 0.129367666 22.16620661
172 0.106115827 17.66170755
173 0.141189947 22.80614976
174 0.138597606 21.77210645
175 0.208358758 32.3500519
176 0.151947177 21.11878186
177 0.153140434 21.10540548
178 0.137582747 17.49821573
179 0.186509558 23.43227561
180 0.217174059 25.87618386
181 0.462111769 55.70328366
182 0.414988312 45.46146453
183 0.454498717 50.3311408
184 0.476314527 47.89701726
185 0.447262531 48.56788899
186 0.481994126 52.62130605
187 0.524246487 63.89627307
188 0.56224745  69.01760401
189 0.406703077 50.07195008
190 0.38165908  49.16083937
191 0.40074206  53.04605039
192 0.359433444 48.67690609
193 0.358658893 50.1438443
194 0.465845137 61.780139
195 0.330123279 50.37872484
196 0.312026154 43.93057202
197 0.438793876 54.41460723
198 0.540941398 72.82641712
199 0.365916126 54.77629477
200 0.299116632 44.30538503
201 0.242739544 37.05265813
202 0.292991779 45.80853328
203 0.227228112 35.17674114
204 0.216239634 32.38608117
205 0.326013871 47.44305647
206 0.351140786 48.63794374
207 0.326286327 43.04200586
208 0.413041691 54.81531804
209 0.408561562 52.83947685
210 0.385187382 48.53497344
211 0.35742707  46.80461621
212 0.398243487 51.55554333
213 0.390547226 51.41482806
214 0.433657644 57.55750654
215 0.439360937 57.07929738
216 0.412329949 53.84627423
217 0.423235294 56.83998431
218 0.352377473 49.37594046
219 0.407564482 56.71937744
220 0.312531561 44.40082756
221 0.38449747  55.92575185
222 0.310966853 44.17271316
223 0.293381231 43.95884798
224 0.277955177 40.96773487
225 0.341124104 49.09284599
226 0.371180002 52.8189418
227 0.467524422 67.31346376
228 0.391291589 54.542343
229 0.402303643 54.83195753
230 0.48065174  64.80996075
231 0.401001866 52.237621
232 0.398708381 53.5160605
233 0.368267551 48.62222553
234 0.441542804 60.79245318
235 0.434771005 60.70216643
236 0.505802946 67.88182472
237 0.54987077  70.69956645
238 0.510252324 67.48395228
239 0.383951522 54.51432689
240 0.234825767 39.15945666
241 0.387795738 57.57235011
242 0.320637127 51.02952158
243 0.34415951  57.16252927
244 0.383883518 68.65434394
245 0.525570839 97.22594311
246 0.478384037 75.87145881
247 0.510522365 69.93771418
248 0.424795035 57.95776657
249 0.523655629 71.62327782
250 0.450358852 62.19320112
251 0.524832186 72.4696227
252 0.64862245  89.72470481
253 0.468529488 63.28746285
254 0.365019322 45.81381814
255 0.4882781   70.80242591
256 0.411259664 54.33403771
257 0.451696231 63.85310548
258 0.470235234 64.49223536
259 0.419845388 58.88540282
260 0.540265948 74.86967462
261 0.371150873 51.23891016
262 0.529457857 69.08291061
263 0.506669768 65.56823029
264 0.49688481  67.52813063
265 0.525752668 69.71800889
266 0.529222132 76.27133378
267 0.462694632 66.63209436
268 0.406277643 60.76928132
269 0.649385409 84.82941831
270 0.592245942 75.75127723
271 0.457067603 57.87689689
272 0.483883665 53.3101069
273 0.495176209 55.94016649
274 0.389443369 49.09857419
275 0.340182674 42.75767793
276 0.467457772 55.31061605
277 0.520337671 65.86225218
278 0.433227419 56.37697401
279 0.490119594 63.16326521
280 0.619353884 79.26767718
281 0.551473022 68.66112753
282 0.584300817 68.00166204
283 0.513560326 62.39170901
284 0.558527338 61.87028341
285 0.51143421  60.64564227
286 0.515225187 59.33611953
287 0.526600459 60.07983743
288 0.469717104 72.53142849
289     82.1526615
290 0.41036587  59.21675376
291 0.484157694 72.31775066
292 0.351256329 53.26413261
293 0.406770843 57.14865954
294 0.341695912 48.96664718
295 0.435356763 62.96839029
296 0.492597473 67.95886661
297 0.399055018 58.96455141
298 0.515747191 76.40183467
299 0.438419609 62.95807334
300 0.515127352 72.14535724
```

Comment: Does this answer and thred help  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53703152/8806649 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```r
df <- read.table(text = "1   0.173391562 28.59395158
2   0.214361872 33.7366968
3   0.308646363 46.2949179
4   0.257708524 37.89447248
5   0.224897551 34.32860265
6   0.145171163 28.08528395
7   0.173999818 24.80078261
8   0.270944328 32.50899326
9   0.261010924 29.01270011
10  0.361983723 36.3893962", header = FALSE)

scaleFactor <- max(df$V2) / max(df$V3)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(V1)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = V2, colour = "V1")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = V3*scaleFactor, colour = "V2")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="V1", sec.axis=sec_axis(~./scaleFactor, name="V2"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>